# Korean texts are going as junk in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, character-encoding, internationalization

Whenever i am sending Korean text in AJAX request with parameter server receive it as junk value.

I need solution for this.

Thanks.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
url : '/login?username='+username,
cache: false,
type : 'post',
dataType : 'text',
contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
success:function(data){
    alert('success');
}
```

});

Hi Deceze, in the server side we have "Spring Controller",
and the method looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-
form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody String login(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
    // Code
}
```

And the received username is "íêµ­" when i enter "한국" (korea).

Comment: Please describe all your attempts (code) and settings related to encoding on the client and on the server.

Comment: Only i have set the "contentType" in jquery's "ajax()". Like : contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'.

Comment: I have only described the "contetType" in the jquery's ajax method. No server side setting has done. In the server side we have "Spring Controller" to receive it.

Comment: How are you treating the data server side? What does "junk" look like and why are you sure the *sending* side is the problem?

Comment: Hi Deceze, i have edited the question for you. please look into it. thanks.

Comment: The problem have been solved by adding URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute in the "connector" tag in "server.xml". Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending username as query parameter.
Which happens when you do get.

Use "contents" to send data.

Please refer https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/